# How to check if jQuery support certain browser?

Tags: jquery, browser

I'm working on a project that use jQuery v3.1.0. What I want to do is, if a user is using a browser (ie. very old browser) that is not compatible with my jQuery, I want to display a message on the front screen saying that "your browser is not supported".

How to do that?

Comment: Related: https://jquery.com/browser-support/

Comment: I would assume the answer would revolve around feature detection.  You don't really care what the version of the browser is.  Just that is supports the features that jQuery uses for what your page actually uses.  So if you can identify those features and detect their non-existance, you can throw up an info message and abandon logical initialization

Comment: To add to @Taplar's comment, [Modernizr](https://modernizr.com/) provides feature detection code.